# Inotify listening to moved_from/moved_to events

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, inotify

I'm using inotify to listen to events on a directory `IN_MOVED_FROM`/`IN_MOVED_TO` pair. Here is the simple assembly program:

```
SYS_exit equ 0x3C

SYS_inotify_init equ 253

SYS_read equ 0x00
MEMPAGE_SIZE equ 4096

SYS_inotify_add_watch equ 254
IN_MOVED_FROM equ 0x40
IN_MOVED_TO equ 0x80

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, SYS_inotify_init
    syscall
    mov r13, rax            ;storing inotify instance

    mov rax, SYS_inotify_add_watch
    mov rdi, r13
    mov rsi, watcher_dir
    mov rdx, IN_MOVED_TO
    syscall 

    mov rax, SYS_inotify_add_watch
    mov rdi, r13
    mov rsi, watcher_dir
    mov rdx, IN_MOVED_FROM
    syscall

    mov rax, SYS_read
    mov rdi, r13
    mov rsi, buf
    mov rdx, MEMPAGE_SIZE
    syscall          <------ I set gdb breakpoint here

    mov eax, SYS_exit
    mov rdi, 0x00
    syscall

section .bss
    buf resb MEMPAGE_SIZE           ;reserving a page
section .data
    watcher_dir: db '/home/me/asm/inotify/data', 0
```

Ok I run the program in gdb with breakpoint set to reading from `inotify` descriptor and examine the

```
struct inotify_event {
     int      wd;       /* Watch descriptor */
     uint32_t mask;     /* Mask describing event */
     uint32_t cookie;   /* Unique cookie associating related
                           events (for rename(2)) */
     uint32_t len;      /* Size of name field */
     char     name[];   /* Optional null-terminated name */
};
```

And when I move a file as follows

```
mv data/test data/test.moved
```

I got only one event `IN_MOVED_FROM`

```
(gdb) x/1xw $rsi + 4                                                                                      
0x600138:       0x00000040
```

The lenght is `0x10:`

```
(gdb) x/1xw $rsi + 12
0x600140:       0x00000010
```

and

```
(gdb) x/1xw $rsi + 32
0x600154:       0x00000000
```

But I expected `IN_MOVED_TO` event in the `buf` (get lost?). When I swap the order of the `inotify_add_watch` in the code the first again get lost. Why?

Comment: Why do you need to use assembly to process `inotify` events?

Comment: @Barmar This is not for production. I'm learning x86 assembly and linux syscalls.

Comment: Use `strace`. Also, rewrite in C to see if it works. Repeat the `read` to see whether the other notification is just buffered (yeah I see you _could_ get multiple in a single read, but maybe it's just not happening).

Comment: @Jester I used and saw exactly one event like I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an assembly problem, you just used the system call wrong. You forgot to specify `IN_MASK_ADD`. This is what [man inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) says:

> IN_MASK_ADD
>
> If a watch instance already exists for the filesystem
>      object corresponding to pathname, add (OR) the events in
>      mask to the watch mask (instead of replacing the mask).

Admittedly it's counter-intuitive that `inotify_add_watch` replaces by default and only adds if you ask for it explicitly.

Comment: And this really works. Thanks much! My fault, did not read docs careful enough.